# move to python?

Tags: python

Need to know why would someone move to python, well may be for intrest of learning new thing ( i have that intrest) but what i will get if i learned python, why should i use python

i am not starting a debate here on which is better language or anything like that. just need to know the speciality of python that makes it very different from all other languages

that made it grow a lot (in number of developers) in 2010 as i read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I tried it, I thought Python was about as deep as the characters from its namesake "Monty Python's Flying Circus"  ... was I ever mistaken!

It's got the lot and more, and is very well documented, and consistant and simple in its format...

How much will you benefit from it? Probably a lot, because as you say, you are interested.  That counts for a lot... Put the effort into it, and you will benefit..  Why are so many people using it?  Because it is so competent.

PS.. I have rather elementary Python skills, but (in this case) I know a good thing when I see it.  There seems to be a library available for whatever you can think of.

Other languages can do the same, so it probably boils down to.. Do you like the feel of it?

Answer (score 2):

Just read about it here: http://www.python.org/about/

In fact, your is a very subjective question and difficult to answer and it depends upon your application and it is your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , about my question I was afraid of thinking about my question as subjictive  , i need as answer pure facts points of things that make python different than others only